# dynamicIpSecurity is not Working on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In Azure WebApp, we defined DynamicIpRestriction as follows:.

```
<security>
  <dynamicIpSecurity enableLoggingOnlyMode="false" enableProxyMode="true">
    <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="10" />
    <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="30" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="500" />
  </dynamicIpSecurity>
  <ipSecurity enableProxyMode="true" allowUnlisted="false" >
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="1.2.3.4" subnetMask="255.255.255.255" />
  </ipSecurity>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The WebApp consists of ASP.NET 4.8.
With this definition, if 10 requests were made at the same time, more than 11 requests were expected to be rejected at 403.
However, I started 100 concurrent threads in Apache JMeter and made 10 repeated requests, but never 403.
Is there a mistake in the definition?

I would appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have set the Dynamic Ip Security in App Service. Using below steps
- Goto App Service, **Goto Advanced Tools** under development tools Click on **Go** as below

[image]

- Now it will take you to the below page as shown & Clik on **Site Extensions**

[image]

- Goto **Gallery** & search for **Dynamic** and click on **search** button and add it.

[image]

- After adding, we will be redirected to the below page where you can add your **Dynamic Ip Security settings** as below

[image]

-After updating the settings, Go back to **Overview** and click on **Restart** as below. So, the setting will update for app service

[image]

_ Open Apache JMeter as below

[image]

- Use the URL of App Service and hit on **execute**

[image]

- Goto view result in table to see the **Output**

[image]