# Dynamic IP Restriction with HTTP/2

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are considering using DynamicIpRestriction to deny excessive access from a single IP in Azure App Service.

As a question, in the case of HTTP/2, it is doubtful whether it is effective to deny excessive access using this function.
In the case of HTTP/1.1, the number of simultaneous connections is restricted to 6 due to client side (browser) restrictions.
We are aware that we can limit the number of concurrent requests by maxConcurrentRequests, but
In the case of HTTP/2, parallel requests can be made on the same socket, and there is no upper limit.

Could you tell me if there is a best practice to reject excessive access with DynamicIpRestricion when using HTTP/2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you tell me if there is a best practice to reject excessive access with DynamicIpRestricion when using HTTP/2?

As per this Azure Blog  [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/announcing-http-2-support-in-azure-app-service/), HTTP/2 is an advanced version of HTTP/1.1 where only few changes made in it such as Http/2 has only 1 TCP/IP Connection, fully multiplexed, binary model, single connection usage for parallelism, overhead reduction by using header compression process.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As per my research, I didn’t find the alternative way for protecting the app service from attacks (DDoS) using the “**Dynamic IP Restriction**” feature and the process for it same as  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74580437/16630138)  after enabling the HTTP/2 and working as expected.